# Pop-up on event handler in MOSS 2007?

Tags: 2007, event-handlers

I have written an event handler using ItemDeleting event , instead of showing default error page when user try to delete a document from document Library I want to show a warning message in Pop-up box ( Javascript)..

Regards
Ash..

Answer (score 2):

It is in SP2007 event handlers not possible to open a dialog or redirect users to another page! SP2010 has improved the object model with the [RedirectUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventpropertiesbase.redirecturl.aspx) property to allow event handlers to redirect users to another page. But to my knowledge it is still not possible to open a dialog from an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Application pages for custom Error page

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. Thanks.